# Multiple pages with multiple subreport by crystal reports

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

Any body have an idea how to set multiple sub-report with multiple pages using crystal reports. i have a two sub-report placing with one main report but when displaying this are showing in one page with on by on. So how can i avoid this?

Thank you,[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, from the Report -> section expert insert a second detail section. It will create detail a and detail b. Insert a subreport in each detail and this should solve your problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to the section where sub report is placed and `Right click` and go to section expert go to `Paging` tab and check then option `new page after`.